# How to execute bat file using node.js with IIS server(windows)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, express, iis

I'm stuck on below code please check it out:-

this is my .bat file:
**runnpm.bat**

```
@echo off
npm i
npx cross-env NODE_ENV=prod nodemon dist/app.js
```

This is my **web.config** file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="iisnode" path="script.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
        </handlers>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReqToServerjs">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="script.js" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <iisnode nodeProcessCommandLine="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" />        
        <security>
            <authorization>
                <add accessType="Allow" users="?" />
            </authorization>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And this is what i'd created but not sure it's working fine or not:-

```
const { spawn, exec } = require('node:child_process');

const ls = exec("runnpm.bat");

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

ls.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

Below screenshot was an error of .bat file not executing please check it:-
[image: ERROR PERMISSION SS]

Note:-
**Server was working fine if i'm target directy app.js file thought web.config file**

I want just execute .bat file thought web.config file or if you have any better idea tell me please :), thanks in advance :).

Comment: 1. Calling `npm` from a web app (via your batch file) is terrible, as that developer tool tries to build up a cache (as the error page indicated) for the application pool identity and fails naturally as that account is typically weak. 2. Spinning out child processes from a web app is also bad, as you easily lose control of them. What exactly are you trying to do? Web apps have typical "DON'T"s, so developers should revise their designs and choose safer paths.

Comment: As mentioned, you need to pay attention to its permissions. Have you configured the corresponding application pool with `Full control` permissions? This might help you.

Comment: @XudongPeng yes i'd already done that step.

Comment: @LexLi okay thanks :)